# how to start selenium properly?

Tags: linux, bash, selenium

Right now, on each server, I start selenium by doing

```
pkill Xvfb

Xvfb :1 -screen 5 1366x768x24 +extension RANDR &

export DISPLAY=:1.5

curl localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--use-gl=osmesa" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -log /home/jenkins-user/log/selenium.log &
```

Problem is that often selenium connection dies and I have to restart selenium process. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are seems running tests on localhost, not distributed, so do you really need to use selenium server? can't you switch to WebDriver?

Comment: how do I switch to webdriver?

Comment: it's explained here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp